# JS, How to set textarea values

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me how can I set textbox value?

```
Site: https://signup.live.com/signup
```

I tried this one

```
document.getElementById("MemberName").value="Luxury_UAE_EA@hotmail.com"
document.getElementById("iSignupAction").click();
```

Comment: What you has works fine... it populates text area and clicks the button..  the issue is that microsoft has other events that inspect your data and decide whether or not its a valid address and/or present you with a split input with account and domain separate... you'll have to figure out what triggers those inspections to occur because it does not appear to be on onchange event handler

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't mean textbox  but **textarea** instead.
Just give the textarea an id and store the desired value on the element which you had tried to achieve.

```js
document.getElementById("MemberName").value="Luxury_UAE_EA@hotmail.com"
```

```html
<textarea id='MemberName'>test</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I tried your code but it didn't work! Can you try it on this site [link](https://signup.live.com/signup)